# Cert's altnames are totally unexpected resulting in SSL verification failure

Tags: networking, security, ssl

I keep getting SSL verification failures when trying to connect to a REST API at esi.evetech.net. It appears that the cert's altnames are totally different from what I would expect.

From Postman, with SSL verification on:

```
GET https://esi.evetech.net/latest/universe/categories/
Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: esi.evetech.net. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.upp.ft.com
```

Is it possible that I am subject to a MITM attack? The domain ft.com obviously belongs to Financial Times and should have nothing to do with the game EVE Online (the API of which I am trying to access).

Furthermore, I have connection issues to this API on another computer in my home network as well when using 3rd party tools. Does this mean my router and whole LAN has been compromised?

How can I analyze what exactly is going on? I am familiar with the basics of networking but not enough with the applicable tools to figure this out on my own. Much thanks for any help!

Comment: What IP addresses does the hostname resolve to? Do they look correct for the site? Do you get different results if you ask a different DNS server?

Comment: Indeed, this ended up being a DNS issue with my ISP. When I tried Google's (8.8.8.8) and Cloudflare's (1.1.1.1) DNS, everything went back to normal. I suppose the IP would have previously belonged to ft.com and that clashed with the current certificate for esi.evetech.net causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google's (8.8.8.8) or Cloudflare's (1.1.1.1) DNS service solved the issue. Thus it was probably either a scuffed DNS server, bad TTL setting or something like that with my ISP.